# How to use NavigationView with standard Android themes?

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-theme, android-design-library

I've tried to integrate NaviogationView.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    NavigationView navigationView = new NavigationView(this);
    setContentView(navigationView);
}
```

But it throws `java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0`
After that I tried to add `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"` in AndroidManifest

```
<activity android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" android:name="MyActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
```

And It doesn't crash. Is there any solution to use standard Android theme and NavigationView?

Here is a full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapp/com.example.myapp.MyActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Error inflating class android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:93)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:149)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
        at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:84)
        at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:15)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:93)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:149)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:84)
            at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:747)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:815)
        at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:151)
        at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:147)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(NavigationMenuView.java:39)
        at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuView.<init>(NavigationMenuView.java:35)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:482)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
            at android.support.design.internal.NavigationMenuPresenter.getMenuView(NavigationMenuPresenter.java:93)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:149)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:88)
            at android.support.design.widget.NavigationView.<init>(NavigationView.java:84)
            at com.example.myapp.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Post your style and the full stacktrace

Comment: There is no style. I use standard style from AppCompat support library.

Comment: Post the full stacktrace

Comment: Just posted stacktrace

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti even I am facing the same issue. We are actually supporting app from >5.0 and so we want to remove compatibility libraries. We only want to use design support library, just for the NavigationView, with knowing that Design support library depends on v4 and v4 appcompat libraries and it will include it in our build. But then issue is we want to use standard material theme i.e. Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that we are the only one who has this exception. :) Anyway, there are some relevant issues regarding this error. The solution is using a `NavigationView` compatible theme.

```
<style name="Theme.YourApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
   ...
</style>
```

And then use that style in AndroidManifest as this:

```
  <application
   ...
   android:theme="@style/Theme.YourApplication">
  <activity
```

Comment: didn't worked for me. I find the problem when running the app in 4.4.4 android but not in 6.0

Answer (score 0):

NavigationView is designed to use it nested in a DrawerLayout. See here  [Android Developers Blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.it/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) for some snippet example.